# Coded UI Test - WinEdit control's search properties doesn't allow searching on AutomationID

Tags: coded-ui-tests

thanks in advance for you help!

I'm writing a CodedUITest that includes entering text into a textbox.  I'm having trouble finding the control, because it hasn't been named.  It has an AutomationId, but when I try to use it, I get an error that it's not a valid search property.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to get the parent(s) object and enumerate through the children until you find the desired object. With vs2013 at least, you can use the crosshair and child navigator to verify its position on the page. For instance, if the text box is the 5th element in the main window

```
 IEnumerator<UITestControl> appt = uiMainWindowControl.GetChildren().GetEnumerator();

 int i=0;
 while (appt.MoveNext() && i<5){
   i++;
 }    
 Mouse.click(appt.Current);
 Keyboard.SendKeys("Enter Text");
```

Comment: I think you meant `i<5`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Textbox` in Coded UI is probably a `WinTextBox`.  Change it to `WpfTextBox` and you'll be able to use the `AutomationId`.